# Design a Data Structure for web server to store history of visited pages

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The server must maintain data for last n days. It must show the most visited pages of the current day first and then the most visited pages of next day and so on.

I'm thinking along the lines of hash map of hash maps. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outer hash map with key of type date and value of type hash map.

Inner hash map with key of type string containing the url and value of type int containing the visit count.

Example in C#:

```
// Outer hash map    
var visitsByDay = 
    new Dictionary<DateTime, VisitsByUrl>(currentDate, new VisitsByUrl());

...

// inner hash map
public class VisitsByUrl
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> Urls { get; set; }

    public VisitsByUrl()
    {
        Urls = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    public void Add(string url)
    {
        if (Urls[url] != null)
            Urls[url] += 1;
        else
            Urls.Add(url, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking in the same direction. This sounds like an efficient solution. Thanks for you help !

Comment: this regurgitates Karthik's expectations without any consideration of his stated functional requirement - there is only one, and not very realistic, but: "It must show the most visited pages of the current day first and then the most visited pages of next day and so on".  Hash maps aren't sorted, and yours is keyed on URL - how are you going to find the most visited page?  Brute force iteration, which for a hash map is typically slower than vector iteration.  Hash maps allow fast intraday updates, but why use an outer hash map when an array/vector of N is better compacted and faster?

Comment: @Tony: I didn't say it's the one and only solution. It may be not sophisticated/complicated/efficient enough for the perfectionist type of developer. Thanks for the downvote anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a hash for each day that has will of the type :-

And a queue of length n. which will have these hashes for each day. Also you will store seperate hash totalHits which will sum all of these

```
Class Stats {
        queue< hash<url,hits> > completeStats;
        hash<url,hits> totalStats;
    public:-
        int getNoOfTodayHits(url) {
             return completeStats[n-1][url];
        }
        int getTotalStats(url) {
            return totalStats[url];
        }
        void addAnotherDay() { 
         // before popping check if the length is n or not :) 
         hash<url,hits> lastStats = completeStats.pop();
         hash<url,hits> todayStats;
         completeStats.push_back(todayStats);
           // traverse through lastStats and decrease the value from total stats;
        }
        // etc.

};
```

Comment: Interesting solution, very nice. Thank you. You chose to use a queue of hash tables instead of hash of hash. Any particular reason you chose this ?? I would assume you would have to scan through the entire queue when searching for stats give a date. What is your thought flow?

Comment: I dont need to handle the dates for keys in hash :) Pop Push works :P

Answer (score 1):

We can have a combination of Stack & Hash Map.

We can create an Object of URL and timestamp, then push it onto the Stack.
Most recent visited Url will be on the top.

We can use the timestamp combined with URL to create a key, which is mapped to the count of visited Urls.

In order to display most visited pages in chronological order, we can pop the stack, create a key and fetch the count associated with the Url. Sort them while displaying.

Time complexity: O(n) + Sort time (depends on the number of pages visited)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you want. For example, do you want to store the actual data for the pages in the history, or just the URLs? If somebody has visited a page twice, should it show up twice in the history?

A hash map would be suitable if you wanted to store the data for a page, and wanted each page to show up only once.

If, as I'd consider more likely, you want to store only the URLs, but want each stored multiple times if it was visited more than once, an array/vector would probably make more sense. If you expect to see a lot of duplication of (relatively) long URLs, you could create a set of URLs, and for each visit store some sort of pointer/index/reference to the URL in question. Note, however, that maintaining this can become somewhat non-trivial.